# How to solve double-modulo issue for obtaining "0"in c#

Tags: c#, .net, casting, double, modulo

I am under s situation where i find modulo of  2.0 %0.1 which as result of double variable returns "0.09999" not "0".

My code to do this is:

```
    var distanceFactor = slider.Value % step; //This do not return 0 when Value=2.0 and step=0.1
    if (distanceFactor != 0)
    {
        slider.Value -= distanceFactor;
    }    
    elseif(distanceFactor == 0)
    {
       //do something here
    }           
    txtblUnits.Text = Math.Round(slider.Value, 1).ToString();
```

How to obtain the control in `elseif` condition when Value=2.0 and step=0.1 ?

Comment: You can check if distanceFactor-step is smaller than a predefined epsilon value. By the way modulo on doubles is not a great idea...

Comment: Modulus shouldn't be used with not integer values as, in mathematics, is an integer operator. You are trying to do mod(2, 0.1) and that is the same than doing mod(20,1)

Comment: Look at the provided 'duplicate question' link, there is the equation for what takes place with a modulo operator ... just do it that long-hand way: ... `double a, b, r; a = 120; b = .05; 
r = a - Math.floor(a / b) * b;`

Answer (score 3):

Modulo `%` has no sense with floating number. You should multiply and cast it to int before applying the operator.

```
var distanceFactor = ((int) (slider.Value * 10D)) % (int) (step * 10D);
```

Comment: i cannot do that because this slider.Value is obtained by moving slider and it's in double and if i make it decimal then it will avoid the small drag of slider progree which is printed on textblock.

Answer (score 1):

You can round the distance factor to 0 decimal in the if condition, like this

```
if (Math.Round(distanceFactor,0) != 0)
{
    slider.Value -= distanceFactor;
}    
else
{
   //do something here
}
```

Comment: now bothof the condition are true... if and aslo elseif

Comment: oh right, I changed the code. thanks.

Comment: what is distancefactor= 0.9999 ?

Comment: logically it goes to else part

Comment: i cannot do that because this slider.Value is obtained by moving slider and it's in double and if i make it decimal then it will avoid the small drag of slider progree which is printed on textblock.

Answer (score 1):

`Double` will not work for modulus operator so Using modulus with floating point numbers is never a good idea so better to use `decimal` instead.

```
decimal slider = 2.0M, step = 0.1M;
var distanceFactor = slider % step; //This will return 0 when Value=2.0 and step=0.1
if (distanceFactor != 0)
{
    slider -= distanceFactor;
}
else if (distanceFactor == 0)
{
    //do something here
}
txtblUnits.Text = Math.Round(slider, 1).ToString();
```

`txtblUnits.Text` will have `2.0`

Comment: slider id uielement so its value is always double. we are not assigning manually it is obtained by draging the slider.

Comment: Then simply cast it to decimal as `decimal slider = (decimal)slider.Value;`

Comment: i cannot do that because this slider.Value is obtained by moving slider and it's in double and if i make it decimal then it will avoid the small drag of slider progree which is printed on textblock.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented on your post, in order to work with modulus operator correctly, try to do something like this:

```
string valueDecimalsString = (slider.Value - Math.Floor(slider.Value)).ToString();

int valueDecimals = valueDecimalsString.Substring(valueDecimalsString.IndexOf('.') + 1).Length;

//The same with step

int decimals = (valueDecimals > stepDecimals) ? valueDecimals : stepDecimals;

int value = (int)(slider.Value * Math.Pow(10, decimals))

//the same with step

var distanceFactor = value % stepValue;
```

Comment: could you please also explain in words your logic  ? thanskj

Comment: For sure :) As modulus is and integer operator, what we do here is to get the same division with only integer numbers. We multiply each number by 10 to the nth power, being n the max of decimals in those numbers.